# $f$ has a limit if and only if $f_1$ has a limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let a function be given as $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $I$ be an open interval in $\mathbb R$ and let $c \in I$. If $f_1$ is the restriction of $f$ to $I$, we need to show that $f_1$ has a limit at $c$ if and only if $f$ has a limit at $c$.

I was able to deal with the part where $f$ has a limit at $c$ implies $f_1$ has a limit at $c$. I am having a hard time to prove/imagine the converse.

Let us say that  $f_1$ has a limit at $c$, i.e say, $f_1(x)\to L$ for $x\to c$.

That means, that if I take any $x$ in $\delta$-neighborhood around $c$ in $I$, $f(x)$ should belong to some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $L$.

But that doesn't mean that any $x$ in $\delta$-neighborhood around $c$ in $\mathbb R$, $f(x)$ also belongs to some $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $L$, does it ?

Can anyone help ?

Comment: $f_1$ is $f$ in $I$ so if $f_1$ has a limit then so does $f$. Let $\epsilon$ be given and choose $\delta$ small enough that $|x-c|\lt\delta$ implies $|f_1(x) - L|\lt\epsilon$. Since $f(x) = f_1(x)$ in $I$ $|f(x) - L|\le\epsilon$ so the limit exists.

Comment: The above statement will also hold true when $I$ is closed, won't it ?
But actually it doesn't.
I am not sure what's the role of this 'open' or 'closed' interval.
Can you explain ? @JohnDouma

Comment: $I$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$. The two functions $f$ and $f_1$ are one and the same in that interval. You can choose $\delta$ small enough so that all of the $x$s are in $I$. Thus, everything true about $f_1$ will be true of $f$ and vice versa. However, you may run into a problem on a closed interval if $c$ is at the edge of the interval.

Comment: " $Lt_{x->c}f_1$ exists for $f:I->R$, $c \in I$, $I$ a closed interval in $R$, doesn't imply $Lt_{x->c}f$ exists for $f:R->R$.."
To see this, I considered a function $h$ such that, $h(x)=1$ for $x\geq 0$ and $h(x)=-1$ for $x<0$. Taking $I=[0,\infty)$, for any given $\epsilon >0$, an open interval can be found around $0$ in $I$ and hence $Lt_{x->0}h$ exists over $I$, whereas over $R$, $Lt_{x->0}h$ doesn't exist. Is this example suitable ? @JohnDouma